# Can't get any files in the Content & Script folder to load in C# ASP.NET MVC application in VS

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

Having some problems here with a web application that was checked into a code repository.

Basically, this application in particular will not display any images, .js, or .css which are all located in the Content & Script folders. Only the raw HTML shows while running. This occurs specifically after doing a fresh pull from our code repository and running locally through Visual Studio. When you inspect the files in the console when its running, all the files are completely empty. The console is also giving a ERROR 500 error file not found (IIRC) The files are definitely in the project locally and they are showing in the Solution Explorer.

I am the only one who actively works on development for this application and I don't run into these problems with my machine.  When you pull from the code repository on another computer, the problems start.  However, no other applications with an extremely similar architecture have this problem after pulling fresh for the repository. I tried creating brand new web applications with exact same settings and files on the computers affected and they loaded perfectly.

The link to the file looks normal too, it matches with the production server which works.

The application is using bundles and most of the bundles look like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js",                       
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-timepicker.js",
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-confirmation.js",
                       "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"));`

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(                
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-timepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-sortable.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-select.min.css"));
```

Things I have tried:

- Adding the .js and .css files in _Layout.cshtml page manually instead
  of with bundle.
- Replacing all the normal files with .min.js or .min.css and vice
  versa
- Changing authentication methods for access
- Changing permissions on Content Folder
- Recreating virtual directory
- Using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019

I am stumped, anyone have any suggestions or recommendations? I can answer any questions that arise.

Comment: This is not supposed to cause this error but just a double check: Are the file included in the project? toggle the `Show All Files` at the top of your solution explorer and make sure these file were included in the project.

Comment: @Bosco Just double checked, all files were included in the project. They are showing up in the solution explorer. Does not have that yellow icon next to the files

Comment: can you show the bundle referencing the `Content` directory

Comment: @Bosco I updated original post. I should clarify this is also affecting the Scripts fodler

Comment: @Degausser Use *.js file rather than *.min.js. also  *.css file rather than *.min.css.

Comment: Looking at all you have tried, I can only give more suggestions. Try pulling the code from the repository to somewhere like the Desktop or someother location like the logged-in user's director. I know you must have checked the git repository with the browser for the files, and as you said the files are there physically, can you open the files and try doing an edit, probably add a character and remove it back, then save the file.

Comment: Use Debugger tab in IE-> Inspect Element and see which Content and Script files are being loaded and from which location.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to commit/push *.csproj* file as well, this file has link to all your files in the project.

Comment: I just checked, and there is a .csproj in the vault and locally on the computer affected. Has all the links to the files